# faster way to implement 2 power float number without using divider

Tags: power-series, exponentiation

I have found codes to implement 2 power float number(2^x where x is float), but, all of them are using dividers(/).

below one is one example where they are using divider for calculating it.
http://www.machinedlearnings.com/2011/06/fast-approximate-logarithm-exponential.html

I want to have a code where there are no dividers with as much high accuracy as possible.

Comment: May we ask why you dislike division? Speed? I suppose the referenced rational functions have already been compared to polynomials (and won)

Comment: I need this for hardware implementation. Division requires more gates and also we have other problems associated with it